# Select Item for android AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

How do I select an item from autocompletetextview adapter and set it as the default item;
say I have a list of countries and I need to set France as default on Autocomplete load?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use setText method of autocompleteTextview

```
 String[] country={"France ","USA","Bangladesh","Canada","Other"};
 autocompleteTextView.setText(country[0]);
```

you can easily use setText,its perfect and work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code......

```
###XML:
    <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="France" 
    >

    <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

###MainActivity:
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        AutoCompleteTextView act;
        String[] country={"France ","USA","Bangladesh","Canada","Other"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            act=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),  
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
            act.setAdapter(adapter);
            act.setThreshold(1);
        }
    }
```